# Sent Bitcoin Cash to Coinbase Bitcoin address

Tags: bitcoin-cash, lost-transactions, cross-chain-recovery

I just mistakenly sent some Bitcoin Cash from Bittrex to my Coinbase Bitcoin wallet & of course they are now stuck. Bittrex have told me  to remove a private key from a Bitcoin address and import it into a BCC wallet to recover these coins. Apart from contacting Coinbase, has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait until Jan 1, 2018 [1]; they are going to add Bitcoin Cash withdraw support. Or you can contact them (of course).

[1] https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/2853600-bitcoin-cash---frequently-asked-questions

Comment: Thanks, I contacted them & hope they'll have pity on my stupidity